# Basic Question: Why does linux-image not match installed version?

Tags: debian, kernel, apt, grub, dpkg

I'm having trouble finding an answer on this from the Googles. I'm using Debian Stretch (which I shamelessly promote as being a great experience).

However, I noticed my kernel was upgrading with basic `apt upgrade` commands.  These upgrades were not reflected in linux-image obtained with `apt search linux-image` or `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`

Example:

```
$ apt search linux-image
  linux-image-4.8.0-2-amd64/now 4.8.15-2 amd64 [installed,local]
  Header files for Linux 4.8.0-2-amd64
```

and

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
  ii  linux-image-4.8.0-2-amd64             4.8.15-2
```

Also `linux-headers`- they're 100% analogous to one another.  Example:

```
$ apt search linux-headers
  linux-headers-4.8.0-2-amd64/now 4.8.15-2 amd64 [installed,local]
  Header files for Linux 4.8.0-2-amd64
```

and

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-headers
  ii  linux-headers-4.8.0-2-amd64           4.8.15-2
```

The same goes for grub, it does not update the name of the image, even when using `update-grub`.  I am not assuming this bug, but it seems like an odd default behavior.  What is the thinking behind the installed image and header versions not being reflected in their names?

Answer (score 4):

The kernel version stored in the package name, *e.g.* 4.8.0-2 in the `linux-image-4.8.0-2-amd64` and `linux-headers-4.8.0-2-amd64` packages, reflects the kernel ABI: it only changes when the ABI changes (which means that external packages depending on the kernel ABI, in particular out-of-tree kernel modules, need to be rebuilt). By convention in Debian, the version used is the upstream kernel version, with a .0 suffix, ignoring the stable release number, followed by a hyphen and a monotonically increasing number which is bumped whenever the ABI changes. Thus all versions of the 4.8.0-2 kernel packages are ABI-compatible, and the ABI was bumped once in the 4.8 series.

This approach has a couple of advantages: you automatically get compatible kernel upgrades, without needing a meta-package update (`linux-image-amd64`, which is maintained in another source package); and you don't need to recompile out-of-tree modules for every kernel update.

In Debian, GRUB ignores the specific version of the kernel, it just lists the package name. This is perhaps less than ideal, but it doesn't matter all that much because you can't have two different ABI-compatible kernels installed, so you don't need to be able to choose between them.

You'll find more information in the Debian kernel handbook, in particular the [section on versions and ABIs](http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-versions.html).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, that was really helpful, and so comprehensive!  I hope this post helps other people, too.